# Logback configuration with external file, log file is empty

Tags: logback

I try configure logging via external file. WLS 10.3.6, startWebLogic.properties include:

```
-Dproject_name_home=D:\path\to\project_home ^
-Dlogging.config=${project_name_home}/conf/logback.xml ^
-Dlogging.path=${project_name_home}/log ^
-Dlogging.file=${project_name_home}/log/out.log ^
-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger
```

out.log was created in project home folder, but it is empty.

according to log logback.xml used inside application, not from external file:

```
19:05:27,621 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
19:05:27,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
19:05:27,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [zip:D:/Weblogic10.3.6/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/project_name/pjckx7/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/logback.xml]
```

What's wrong? Please help to configure logging with external file.

My external logback.xml is:

```
<configuration>

  <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${project_home}/log" />

  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH}/out.log" />

  <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archive/out/out-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
       <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>

   <logger name="package.name" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
   </logger>  
</configuration>
```

Logging configure inside application, application.yml is:

```
logging:
 level:
    package:
        name: DEBUG
 path: ${project_home}/logs
 pattern:
  console: "${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %maskedM%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%wEx}}"
  file: "${FILE_LOG_PATTERN:%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %maskedM%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%wEx}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the next steps for logging configuration via external logback.xml are:

set logging.config (path to external logback.xml) in WLS start file.

also logging levels defined in application.yml need configure in WLS start file (logging.level. parameter, according to question need set logging.level.package.name parameter).

levels for another packages (not defined in application.yml) are configure in logback.xml.

other parameters (logging.path, logging.file) should be deleted.

all other parameters are configure at external logback.xml as before.